# How is Power Distributed in This Case?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, energy-conservation, rotation

I have been reading the working of induction motor, where I came across Torque-slip characteristics where the equation of torque was determined to be (refer figure).

[image]

In the derivation the power lost in the rotor, ie, rotor losses were equated to

$$P_r = 3E_2 I_2 cos(\phi_2)$$

Isn't that RHS term equal to  power developed in rotor rather than power lost by rotor?